# Is Materialize CSS full width slider's HEIGHT responsive?

Tags: css, slider, height, responsive, materialize

I've been searching for this issue for months, never finding a solution, and not understanding how come noone ever asked it before.

It's pretty simple:
Full Width Slider in Materialize: The images in the slider are being cropped. If I resize the window (to a bigger or smaller size) it will adjust and show me the images at full size (not cropped).

Just see the height of the image, it shows a thin image instead of a bigger one, but if you resize the window it'll automatically adjust:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drJWxG

Best regards and thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!!!

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Slyder</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
  <style>
    h1{padding:10px auto, color:#fff}

    .carousel .carousel-item > img {max-width:100%;height:auto;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="carousel carousel-slider">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1" class="responsive-img"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/2" class="responsive-img"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/3" class="responsive-img"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/4" class="responsive-img"></a>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l12 red">
        <h1>Please resize window to see the slider's height change</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({fullWidth: true});

    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: Dear Germa, thanks for your reply. Please see the link in the codepen. When the page loads, you'll see a red box "Please resize window..." that is over the image. The image shows partially. 
IF you modify the browser's width manually with your mouse, you'll see that the red box moves down and now you can see the image in it's full size. Am I clear? Thanks in advance!